# Slider Revolution doesn’t work when activate the Google translator plugin

Tags: jquery, wordpress, revolution-slider

I have installed the google translator plugin and visible in the top toolbar of the page but the issue is when i activate the google translator plugin the Slider Revolution doesn’t work, need a help to solve the issue,
Thanks
Pan

Comment: Hi Pan, can we see the link ot the site with this problem (or screen)?

Comment: Hi Marco, thanks for the reply, actually i have disable the translator at the moment because when i activate it the slider diapers, so i f you need to visit the website hear is the link [link](https://www.give2lanka.info) probably some plugin conflicts because of j query)

Comment: I can not see the site, I'm in the visitor and then he brings me back to the Coming Soon page